# How to switch cron job in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, cron, scheduling

I have two cron jobs in a single class

```
@EnableScheduling
public class RecognizeService {


@Scheduled(cron = "0/4 * * * * ?")
public void recognize1() throws IOException, ParseException {
    //some code
 }

@Scheduled(cron = "0/4 * * * * ?")
public void recognize2() throws IOException, ParseException {
    //some code
 }
}// class end
```

at a time, How can I run only one cron job ? For e.g If  **recognize1** is running and I want to switch on to **recognize2** at that time **recognize1** must be stopped. At a time only one cron job can run.

Comment: It sounds like you solved half of the problem, and want us to solve the other half. But what is the whole problem you're trying to solve? Not running cron jobs mutually exclusive: that's what you came up with, but it could be that there's another approach possible to solve your business problem.

Comment: @Scheduled is used when the cron is run independently as per the given schedule. In your case looks like the second cron can't have it's own schedule and it has to run only after the other is complete. I suggest, in such cases you should combine the two in one cron job

Comment: @AmitPhaltankar , I am using to camera , user may choose recognize1 or recognize2 at that time I have to switch

Comment: @SeverityOne , I want run recognize1 either recognize2 , not both at a time

Comment: I do think that the part of the solution that you came up with is incorrect. Judging from your previous comment, it would make more sense to have one cron job and run different functionality based on the user's choice. For example, run one cron job `recognize` that defers execution to either `recognize1` or `recognize2`.

Comment: like that only..

Comment: one possible way is that you can explicitly stop one scheduler when other is started by putting them in ThreadPoolTaskScheduler and ScheduledFuture

Comment: @DevendraSingh , can you give sample code